# Flask wont play a video in the html

Tags: python, html, video, flask

I have a flask application that is supposed to play a video when the page is loaded but its just showing up in th top left corner and not changing from the first frame of the video

Ive already tried plugging it into the html code but it doesnt work

```
{% extends "base.html"  %}


{% block content %}

<video height="224" width="400" preload="auto" data-video-width="400"  src="../static/chugging.mp4" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; align-items: center"></video>

{% endblock %}
```

I would expect to see it play or at least see a play button somehwere but its just a small frame in the top left corner

Comment: you need to add the `controls` attribute, as well as `muted` and `autoplay` if that's what you want. the size is set by width and height

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Playing video in Flask template

If you have video files in the `static` folder you can access them in templates using `url_for` as like other static files. Documentation of serving static files can be found [in this URL](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files).

Here I am showing an example of playing video file in template.

Directory structure:

```
├── app.py
├── static
│   └── demo.mp4
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Serving video files from Flask template</h2>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src={{ url_for('static', filename="demo.mp4") }} type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: video playing in Flask template]

Comment: I copied exactly what you did, and the video frame loads but doesn't play anything and I can't click the play button. I'm running my flask app with `python -m flask run` and in the terminal I can see a GET request for the video but it returns 206. Can you help please

Comment: Can you check if you are able to play the video using HTML5 only (without Flask/Python)?  Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score -2):

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

After doing all that are given above simply Add these lines in the .py file at the end...It will do the task