# In flask play a video by supplying full path to that video

Tags: python, html, flask, video

I am very new to flask and have learned most of it through chatGPT. However with videos there was a hard stop.

To my understanding the standard way of supplying video files to the client is through a static folder including said videos. This will not work for me, there are 100s of possible videos and more coming all the time.

Is there anyway I can supply the client side with a full path of where the video, .avi file in my case is located, and the client to play that video?

Flask app

```
@app.route('/play_video/<filename>')
def play_video(filename):

    folder_path = session["folder"]
    # avi_file = session["avi_file"]
    print(f"AVI FOLDER: {folder_path}", file=sys.stderr)
    return send_from_directory(folder_path, filename,as_attachment=False)

@app.route('/WEB', methods=['GET','POST'])
def web():
   # Lots of code for finding files
   session["folder"] = folder_path

   return render_template('web.html' avi_file=avi_file)
```

HTML

```
{%block body%}

<form action="/WEB" method="post">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Plot", name="plot_button_pressed">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            {% for column in df.columns %}
            <th>{{ column }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for index, row in df.iterrows() %}
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="selected_row[]" value={{index}}></td>
            {% for value in row %}
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="plots">
            {% if plot_html %}
                {{ plot_html|safe }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <video width="100%" controls>
            <source src="{{ url_for('play_video', filename=avi_file) }}" type="video/avi">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I have tried both supplying the full path to the src="path/to/avi" in html and also some deviations of send_file and send_from_directory. But nothing seems to work and I get no fault messages either..

Comment: Check if this solves your issue, [Playing video in flask template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55963265)

Comment: I have looked at that thread, it concerns videos located in the static folder. My case is that I cannot move all the videos to a static folder, they are located on a cluster. Might be possible if I can map a really large cluster folder but then the videos would be nested within.